# How to create a firewall rule, to block a website for a particular user?

Tags: firewall, iptables, blocking, firewalld

can anybody helps me to make a firewall rule to block a particular website for a particular user. i have a Linux operating system am trying to make that OS like a firewall.

Comment: This question is very broad, and is ill suited for the format on SuperUser. Do some research of your own and come back with specific questions.

Comment: You tagged "firewalld". Are you using that solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily block a website for a particular user - particularly not using just  a firewall.    What you could do - assuming the Linux box is acting as a router - is block an IP address reaching another IP address.

You can map the users machine to a fixed IP address by dynamically assigning a static IP address, and you may be able to add a rule blocking that from address from the destination domains to address - although there may be some fallout, and can be worked around by the user changing their MAC address or statically assigning themselves a different from address.

You could also force everyone through a proxy, and require they log in to the proxy and then use the proxy to do the block.  Hard, messy, breaks https.

Comment: Though you can of course add SSL interception to your proxy setup. If you install a certificate to the client devices, that will fix SSL breakage.

Comment: @dmcoding absolutely (and as  per my answer), but that won't identify the user and assumes a proxy setup - which breaks https even when you install a cert. (It can still work, but I've seen interesting negotiation errors in this kind of setup) . You still need a way to u iquely identify the user.